# Programming in C: Changing member value of struct gives segfault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, typedef

There are quite a few topics on this subject but I haven't been able to find a solution that's worked for me; I am getting a segmentation fault whenever I try to change student_t.member->name. Below is the typedef structure that I am required to use:

```
typedef struct degree_t degree_t;
typedef struct student_t student_t;

struct degree_t {
    student_t* member;
    int course_id;
}

struct student_t {
    char* name;
    int age;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    student_t *students = malloc(sizeof(student_t) * 3);
    degree_t *degrees = malloc(sizeof(degree_t));

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        degrees[i].course_id = 1;
        degrees[i].member->name = "Bob";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can change degrees[i].course_id perfectly fine, but whenever I try to change degrees[i].member -> name, I get a segmentation fault.

GDB indicates that this is a result of the line degrees[i].member->name = "Bob", but I'm don't understand why, and I don't know how to effectively change the value of degrees[i].member->name

Comment: Make sure you allocate memory for *all* pointers, including those inside your `struct`s. Nicely written question by the way, plus one.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping it wouldn't be too much of a nightmare to read. But I am slightly confused with the allocation - which pointers have I missed out on allocating memory for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, you managed to place four errors in that small program.

1. The signature of `main()` should be `main(int argc, char *argv[])`. argv is an **array** of strings found on the command line.
2. You allocate memory for one degree, but in the for-loop you initialize three of them. This leads to a heap corruption.
3. You don't initialize degrees->member, but use it.
4. You allocate memory for three students, but don't use it.

Try this:

```
struct degree_t {
  student_t* member;
  int course_id;
}

struct student_t {
   const char* name;
   int age;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  degree_t *degrees = malloc(3 * sizeof(degree_t));

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      degrees[i].course_id = 1;
      degrees[i].member = malloc(sizeof(student_t));
      degrees[i].member->name = "Bob";
      degrees[i].member->age = 23;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It's working perfectly now - I'm new to memory allocation so (as you can tell) I'm not too good at it.

And thanks for correcting the argv argument as well! I've edited the original post regarding this, as my program does contain the argv[] but I had overlooked this when I wrote my post.

Comment: The argv[] issue isn't relevant as you don't use command line arguments. You could even write `void main() { ... }`, which is wrong but still works.

Comment: It would be sensible to use `int main(void)` since the arguments are ignored.  Using `void` for the return type is only allowed by Microsoft.  On UNIX-like systems, `void main(void)` is unconditionally wrong.